# Keep track of data revisions efficiently

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, python-datetime

I get a data feed like
`datetime,value`.

The API gives me the entire history, about 10,000 observations, and it adds new observations about every hour.

I need to add new data to a dataframe and run some analytics on it and save the df.  Usually I just get new observation when I run my code.

Sometimes some old observations get revised, i.e. the API might change some observation I have already downloaded and processed.

The feed does not flag such revisions and  I need to keep track of that. Suppose I get 2 data revisions (over different calls to the API) each changing the value for `2023-09-12 08:00`

I then need to have the following rows in my df

```
date, value, revision
2023-09-12 08:00, 1000, 0
2023-09-12 08:00, 2000, 1 # <- this is a revised observation. 
2023-09-12 08:00, 1000, 2 # <- this is a second revised observation. 
2023-09-13 06:00, 1500, 0`
```

It is easy to identify and label revisions  by looping over the df and seeing if something changed, but that is SLOW.

just wondering if there was a fast and clever way to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Let's make sure we have an understanding:*

Assuming 2 dataframes,

- one being the **repository** where changes are being tracked
- the other being the **feed** of new data, typically containing

  - old timestamps (history),
  - modified timestamps (revisions)
  - new timestamps

Then *feed* will be filtered to retain only the non-redundant timestamps, numbered by revision, and appended to the repository.

---

**Input data**

*Repository:*

```py
repo = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['date', 'value', 'revision'],
                    data = [['2023-09-01 08:00', 500, 0],
                            ['2023-09-02 08:00', 1000, 0],
                            ['2023-09-02 08:00', 2000, 1]]
                   ).astype({'date':'datetime64[ns]'})

                 date  value  revision
0 2023-09-01 08:00:00    500         0
1 2023-09-02 08:00:00   1000         0
2 2023-09-02 08:00:00   2000         1
```

*Feed:*

```py
feed = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['date', 'value'],
                    data = [['2023-09-01 08:00', 500],   # unchanged
                            ['2023-09-02 08:00', 1000],  # revision: back to 1000
                            ['2023-09-03 08:00', 1500]]  # new timestamp
                   ).astype({'date':'datetime64[ns]'}) 

                 date  value
0 2023-09-01 08:00:00    500
1 2023-09-02 08:00:00   1000
2 2023-09-03 08:00:00   1500
```

---

**Processing**

Step 1: Concatenate both repo and feed, but document each row's source in a temporary column

*Revision:*

```py
revi = pd.concat([repo.assign(source='repo'), 
                  feed.assign(source='feed')]
                ).sort_values(by='date').reset_index(drop=True)

                 date  value  revision source
0 2023-09-01 08:00:00    500       0.0   repo
1 2023-09-01 08:00:00    500       NaN   feed
2 2023-09-02 08:00:00   1000       0.0   repo
3 2023-09-02 08:00:00   2000       1.0   repo
4 2023-09-02 08:00:00   1000       NaN   feed
5 2023-09-03 08:00:00   1500       NaN   feed
```

Step 2. Assign revision number

A little technical, that one, but simply put, the size (`len`) of each group of rows with identical timestamp, is used to calculate a revision number.

```py
aggf = len

revi.loc[revi.revision.isna(), 'revision'] = revi.set_index('date')['revision'].groupby(level=0).agg(aggf).values - 1

                 date  value  revision source
0 2023-09-01 08:00:00    500       0.0   repo
1 2023-09-01 08:00:00    500       1.0   feed
2 2023-09-02 08:00:00   1000       0.0   repo
3 2023-09-02 08:00:00   2000       1.0   repo
4 2023-09-02 08:00:00   1000       2.0   feed
5 2023-09-03 08:00:00   1500       0.0   feed
```

Step 3: Remove feed rows that are not new information

```py
revi = revi.drop_duplicates(subset=['date','source'], keep='last'   # keep only the latest revision for each repo timestamp
          ).drop_duplicates(subset=['date','value'],  keep='first') # remove feed rows that only repeated the repo.

                 date  value  revision source
0 2023-09-01 08:00:00    500       0.0   repo
3 2023-09-02 08:00:00   2000       1.0   repo
4 2023-09-02 08:00:00   1000       2.0   feed
5 2023-09-03 08:00:00   1500       0.0   feed
```

Step 4: Finaly clean the revision dataframe by removing repo rows, then 'source' column

```py
revi = revi[revi.source=='feed'].drop(columns='source')

                 date  value  revision
4 2023-09-02 08:00:00   1000       2.0
5 2023-09-03 08:00:00   1500       0.0
```

Those are the 2 rows from the current feed that are required to be committed to repository:

```
repo = pd.concat([repo, revi]
        ).sort_values(by=['date','revision']
        ).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: @jacoo You're welcome. It was a good question and searching a solution was pleasant. It could be that additional speed might be gained by filtering out redundant feed rows *before* assigning revision numbers. Since revisions are probably rare overall. The provided answer should already represent a significant speed gain.